# ASP.NET MVC Using Render Partial from Within an Html Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an HtmlHelper extension that currently returns a string using a string builder and a fair amount of complex logic.  I now want to add something extra to it that is taken from a render partial call, something like this ...

```
public static string MyHelper(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("Hi There");
    builder.Append(RenderPartial("MyPartialView"));
    builder.Append("Bye!");
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Now of course RenderPartial renders directly to the response so this doesn;t work and I've tried several solutions for rendering partials to strings but the all seem to fall over one I use the HtmlHelper within that partial.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Because this question, although old and marked answered, showed up in google, I'm going to give a different answer.

In asp.net mvc 2 and 3, there's an Html.Partial(...) method that works like RenderPartial but returns the partial view as a string instead of rendering it directly.

Your example thus becomes:

```
//using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
public static string MyHelper(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("Hi There");
    builder.Append(helper.Partial("MyPartialView"));
    builder.Append("Bye!");
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I'd like to highlight this line: `using System.Web.Mvc.Html`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the accepted answer printed out the viewable HTML on the page in ASP.NET MVC5 with for example:

```
@Html.ShowSomething(Model.MySubModel, "some text")
```

So I found the way to [render it properly](https://forums.asp.net/t/2077559.aspx?How%20to%20render%20html%20in%20page%20with%20the%20help%20of%20custom%20html%20helper) was to return an `MvcHtmlString`:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ShowSomething(this HtmlHelper helper, 
      MySubModel subModel, string someText)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(someText);

    sb.Append(helper.Partial("_SomeOtherPartialView", subModel);

    return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't be calling partials from a helper. Helpers "help" your views, and not much else. Check out the RenderAction method from [MVCContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib) (if you need it now) or [MVC v2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/download/) (if you can wait a few more months). You'd be able to pass your model to a standard controller action and get back a partial result.

Comment: In some circumstances yes (probably including this one), but I try to keep my HTML in HTML like files where possible and use Html helpers to do the logic around how to combine them.  This way I still get nice editor features in my html.  However not using render partial is exactly what I've done in this case.