# HTML-Helper function that can render a Partial-View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, html-helper

Is it possible to create a HTML.Helper function that renders a Partial View?

In my project, this would allow me to create a Helper for showing information messages (or error messages). This function would (for example) receive the message itself and would render a partial view with the html for showing that message.
  I know i could just put the html together inside the helper function itself (without using a partial view) but in that case, for changing the looks of the messages shown i would have to mess with code, and not just a partial view file.

Can anyone help me with that one?

Thanks in advance,
Marcelo Myara
Rio de Janeiro-Brazil

Comment: Found it in here:   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086365/asp-net-mvc-using-render-partial-from-within-an-html-helper

:D

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Html.RenderAction` or `Html.Action` ([Difference between Html.RenderAction and Html.Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955261/difference-between-html-renderaction-and-html-action))

```
@Html.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { MyMessage = "test" })
```

OR

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("MyAction", "MyController", new { MyMessage = "test" }) }
```

Comment: Ok, you're right, but in my case, i want to call it from a user defined helper and not strait from a view... So I would implement another Helper (let's say "@RenderErrorMessage") and from this newly created method i would like to render a partial.

Comment: @MarceloMyara You asking about `@helper`? Like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665103/can-i-have-a-global-razor-helper-outside-of-app-code OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825699/how-to-create-global-helper-functions ?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086365/asp-net-mvc-using-render-partial-from-within-an-html-helper

Comment: This question is (almost) exactly what i intended to do... :D