# Models Interfering with Partials

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So currently in my _Layout file, I have a global login and Register system which will show on every page:

```
<div id="global_login_register">
   <div id="login">
      @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
   </div>
   <div id="register">
      @Html.Partial("_RegisterPartial")
   </div>
</div>

@RenderBody()
```

In my loginPartial page I have a @model LoginModel and in my register I have @model RegisterModel. So far everything works, but the problem is when I try to submit another model to the View() it's interfering with the login partials. Is the only way to fix this is to use the ViewBag and save my model onto there?

Comment: You shouldn't use ViewBag to pass your Model to your View. One option is to create a ViewModel that has your main Model class, LoginModel, and RegisterModel as properties. It depends on how many different Views you have. I need more information about your application to give you the best option.

Comment: The problem with above is If I had another controller page, I would have to add it as well model to that ViewModel as well. Wouldnt It be a problem if I had all my Models into a ViewModel class?

Comment: No, you can create a separate ViewModel for the other Controller (Model). That's why I said it depends on how many Models/Controllers you have. But, even if you have a lot of controllers, you can create a BaseViewModel with LoginModel and RegisterModel in it, and then make all other ViewModels inherit from the BaseViewModel.

Comment: Can you post the code for LoginModel, RegisterModel, and their partial views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your partial needs a model, you need to pass it with the partial call: `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", aLoginModel)`. The harder question is where to get `aLoginModel`, and there are a few possible options...

1. Use `@Html.Action(...)` to defer to a separate control (that can build a `LoginModel` for you) - generally not worth the overhead of a full controller lifecycle, but it's a clean solution if you can afford it.
2. Use an interface for your `LoginModel` and require that every view model implement it - almost certainly not a good idea, but it would work.
3. Store the `LoginModel` in `ViewBag/ViewData` using some mechanism that's guaranteed to execute before your views will be rendered.
4. Write your own `Html` helper that knows how to build the `LoginModel` from the `HtmlHelper` context. You could either use that result in the _layout (e.g. `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", Html.LoginModel)`) or put the `Partial` call inside the helper (e.g. `@Html.Login()`).

For anything performance-critical, I would use #4.

Comment: Do you know any great tutorials for #4? This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for all this information. Also why would #2 be a bad idea?

Comment: Example of #4: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5373156/54249

#2 is likely a bad idea because the only reasonable way to implement it is using a model base class - every time I've done this, I've regretted it. Plus you would need to initialize the login-related state at some point in the controller lifecycle (perhaps an `OnActionExecuted` filter that checks if a view model implements the interface).